# Is there a way to have null content in Flutter's Stepper?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to have a stepper display steps , with no user interaction required. However the stepper has a required parameter `content` which displays a selection for the user , something like this.

[image]
I'm simply trying to remove the button selections and merely display a list of steps. This is an example of the expected result.

[image]

I've tried labeling the `content:` as `null` and creating an empty function by `(){}` but none seem to have worked.

Comment: This is all just source code for nearly everything. Have you looked at how the stepper generates the graphic? Edit : Use the Stepper's [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart) and generate a custom widget to suit your needs.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by looking at how the stepper generates graphics. I'm aware that in the [Step documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Step/content.html) its mentioned every step has a 'continue' and 'cancel' button. I'm trying to remove or disable this portion entirely and generate a no-content stepper

Comment: On a side note , if there is a better widget to achieve this expected outcome , perhaps you can point me towards it ?

Comment: I'm saying you could probably just grab the source code for stepper and make it work like you want.

Comment: Oh by that you mean use the Stepper's [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart) to create a custom widget with my own parameters. Yes that would work , one benefit of Flutter being open sourced. I'll edit this into the answer and mark it as accepted , thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for removing button selection,

```
Stepper(
        // any arguments...
        controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            {VoidCallback onStepContinue, VoidCallback onStepCancel}) {
                return Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                     Container(
                        child: null,
                     ),
                     Container(
                        child: null,
                     ),
                  ], // <Widget>[]
                ); // Row
        },
) // Stepper
```

give attention to controlsBuilders.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the buttons you can use the controlsBuilders as stated on a different answer by Jetwiz.
But, the material stepper don't have an option to change the line colors, and moreover, that answer has a bug. If you only have 1 step, a vertical line will show up under the icon.

If you want to fully customize the stepper you'll have to change the material stepper for a different component...I'm using this library to customize my stepper: https://pub.dev/packages/another_stepper